# Show / Hide en items con Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como puedo hacer para que cuando le den **click** al icono de **fontawesome** cambie el icono y muestre el elemento con **id**, si el icono es `fa-arrow-left` cuando el den click debe de cambiar a `fa-arrow-down` y mostrar el contenido con **id** en este caso `id="primerItem"`, y viceversa...
Esto es lo que he intentado:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var icono1 = $( "#icono1" );
    icono1.click(function() {
      $( "#item1 p" ).toggle();
    });

    var icono2 = $( "#icono2" );
    icono2.click(function() {
      $( "#item2 p" ).toggle();
    });

    var icono3 = $( "#icono3" );
    icono3.click(function() {
      $( "#item3 p" ).toggle();
    });

    var icono4 = $( "#icono4" );
    icono4.click(function() {
      $( "#item4 p" ).toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .content-items .sub-content {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .content-items .item {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 25px;
        }

        .content-items .ico {
            display: inline;
            float: right;
            font-size: 25px;
            margin: 15px;
        }

        .content-items p {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #000;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items" style="background-color: pink;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item1" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum incidunt reprehenderit placeat, animi quo perferendis magni doloremque tempore autem ut maiores, molestias vero repellat earum optio similique deleniti explicabo sint?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items"  style="background-color: #727aa0;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono2">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item2" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, quidem quibusdam sint! Eligendi amet delectus magni molestiae eveniet unde, illo voluptas dolorum dicta distinctio, officia ullam dolore eius soluta voluptates.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items" style="background-color: #bb2e46;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono3">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item3" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items" style="background-color: #9abb2e;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono4">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item4" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

El resultado esperado es simple, que cuando le den clic al icono este cambie de icono y muestre el contenido.
 **Caso contrario**: cambie icono y oculte contenido.

**Update #1** 
 Lo que esta pasando en este **Update** es que tengo el icono `arrow-down` pero no muestra el contenido hasta que haga **click**...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.fa-arrow-left', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-arrow-left').addClass('fa-arrow-down');
    $(this).closest('.content-items').find('.item-contenido').show();
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.fa-arrow-down', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-arrow-down').addClass('fa-arrow-left');
    $(this).closest('.content-items').find('.item-contenido').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .content-items .sub-content {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .content-items .item {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 25px;
        }

        .content-items .ico {
            display: inline;
            float: right;
            font-size: 25px;
            margin: 15px;
        }

        .content-items p {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #000;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items" style="background-color: pink;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item1" class="item-contenido" style="padding-top: 20px; display: none;" >
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum incidunt reprehenderit placeat, animi quo perferendis magni doloremque tempore autem ut maiores, molestias vero repellat earum optio similique deleniti explicabo sint?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items"  style="background-color: #727aa0;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono2">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item2" class="item-contenido" style="padding-top: 20px; display: none;" >
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, quidem quibusdam sint! Eligendi amet delectus magni molestiae eveniet unde, illo voluptas dolorum dicta distinctio, officia ullam dolore eius soluta voluptates.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items" style="background-color: #bb2e46;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono3">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item3" class="item-contenido" style="padding-top: 20px; display: none;" >
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, quos esse quo? Neque, quaerat, exercitationem. Voluptas omnis nesciunt porro veritatis culpa quasi. Repellendus culpa corrupti, fugiat sunt quia magni consequuntur.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items" style="background-color: #9abb2e;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono4">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item4" class="item-contenido" style="padding-top: 20px; display: none;">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ratione quo alias fugit maiores enim odio amet, harum provident necessitatibus, error eveniet iste non voluptatibus dolore rem voluptates deleniti quos?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buenas zerokira, ¿puedes explicar con ejemplos el resultado esperado ?  y ¿qué has intentado y qué errores has tenido?  Mira [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b jeje he mejorado mi pregunta, pero lo voy a tener en cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola! Si no usas contenido cargado dinámicamente (AJAX), puedes probar lo siguiente:

Primero agrégale a todos tus items display:none y la misma clase, para usarla como referencia:

```
<div id="cuartoItem" class="item-contenido" style="display: none; padding-top: 20px;">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Luego en Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fa-arrow-left').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-arrow-left').addClass('fa-arrow-down');
    $(this).closest('.content-items').find('.item-contenido').show();
  });
  $('.fa-arrow-down').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-arrow-down').addClass('fa-arrow-left');
    $(this).closest('.content-items').find('.item-contenido').hide();
  });
});
```

En caso de que tengas contenido cargado dinámicamente, el Javascript quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.fa-arrow-left', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-arrow-left').addClass('fa-arrow-down');
    $(this).closest('.content-items').find('.item-contenido').show();
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.fa-arrow-left', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-arrow-down').addClass('fa-arrow-left');
    $(this).closest('.content-items').find('.item-contenido').hide();
  });
});
```

Dime si tienes alguna duda,
¡Saludos!

Comment: he editado mi pregunta de lo que quiero, por favor revisala

Comment: El código que estás intentando hacer te obligará a tener un $().click por cada id que tengas, imagínate si el día de mañana tienes 30 ids, no será escalable.

El código que te propongo es todo lo que necesitas para que funcione, de hecho ni siquiera necesitas los id en rigor, ya que con closest llegas al elemento que corresponde, pruébalo y dime cómo te va.

Comment: en caso de que tenga el arrow-down deberia de mostrarse el contenido, puedes hacer eso?

Comment: Si, la linea $(this).closest('.content-items').find('.item-contenido').show(); es la encargada de hacer eso, ¿No te está funcionando? Esta línea lo que hace es buscar el contenedor content-items más cercano arriba en el DOM, luego desde ese punto busca el .item-contenido que corresponde y con .show() lo muestra.

Comment: he colocado un update #1 editando mi pregunta para que lo mires de acuerdo a tu respuesta, no se en que esta fallando.

Comment: Me está funcionando correctamente, pero ojo que en el item #2 estás comenzando con <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>, tienes dos opciones: O comenzar con <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> como los demás, o comenzar con <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> pero también en el item-contenido correspondiente a ese quitar el display: none;

Answer (score 0):

Ordena tu codigo en funciones sencillas, y combinalas en una lógica simple, de esta forma creas mas lineas de codigo pero resuelves el problema de forma mucho mas escalable y legible.

Básicamente necesitas una función para mostrar y cerrar un item. En caso de hacer click precisas hacer un toggle entre dos clases y mostrar o cerrar un item; y en un principio para que el contenido se muestre correctamente según la clase del icono de la flecha debes normalizar el estado de cada item:

```js
$('.content-items .ico i').each(function(){

  var arrow = $(this);
  arrow.click(function(){ toggleItem(arrow); });  
  normalizeItem(arrow);

});

function showItem(arrow){
  arrow
    .removeClass('fa-arrow-left').addClass('fa-arrow-down')
    .closest('.content-items').find('.item-contenido').show();
}

function hideItem(arrow){
  arrow
    .removeClass('fa-arrow-down').addClass('fa-arrow-left')
    .closest('.content-items').find('.item-contenido').hide();
}

function toggleItem(arrow){
  if(arrow.hasClass('fa-arrow-left')) return showItem(arrow);    
  return hideItem(arrow);
}

function normalizeItem(arrow){
  if(arrow.hasClass('fa-arrow-left')) return hideItem(arrow);  
  return showItem(arrow);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .content-items .sub-content {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .content-items .item {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 25px;
        }

        .content-items .ico {
            display: inline;
            float: right;
            font-size: 25px;
            margin: 15px;
        }

        .content-items p {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #000;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items" style="background-color: pink;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono1">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item1" class="item-contenido" style="padding-top: 20px; display: none;" >
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum incidunt reprehenderit placeat, animi quo perferendis magni doloremque tempore autem ut maiores, molestias vero repellat earum optio similique deleniti explicabo sint?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items"  style="background-color: #727aa0;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono2">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item2" class="item-contenido" style="padding-top: 20px; display: none;" >
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, quidem quibusdam sint! Eligendi amet delectus magni molestiae eveniet unde, illo voluptas dolorum dicta distinctio, officia ullam dolore eius soluta voluptates.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items" style="background-color: #bb2e46;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono3">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item3" class="item-contenido" style="padding-top: 20px; display: none;" >
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, quos esse quo? Neque, quaerat, exercitationem. Voluptas omnis nesciunt porro veritatis culpa quasi. Repellendus culpa corrupti, fugiat sunt quia magni consequuntur.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-items" style="background-color: #9abb2e;">
                    <div class="sub-content">
                        <span class="item">Item</span>
                        <span class="ico" id="icono4">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="item4" class="item-contenido" style="padding-top: 20px; display: none;">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ratione quo alias fugit maiores enim odio amet, harum provident necessitatibus, error eveniet iste non voluptatibus dolore rem voluptates deleniti quos?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

De esta forma no solo tienes un funcionamiento limpio, tienes funciones reutilizables y faciles de mantener por si tu aplicación crece y necesitas combinar funcionalidades para operar con los desplegables.